# In Javascript 2 decimals and comma-separtor in numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to have 2 decimals and comma-separator in numbers in such a way that decimal comes after comma always.

I have tried this example:

```js
const number = 50000;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 2 })
  .format(number));
```

I also need 2 decimals in this number value.

- Input: 50000
- Actual Output: 50,000
- Expected Output: 50,000.00

Above output is needed in my case.

Comment: I think you need to use maximumFractionDigits:2, not maximumSignificantDigits

Comment: use `minimumFractionDigits:2`; `maximumFractionDigits:2` will give you 2 *at the most*, but you seem to require them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is the solution :**

```js
const options = {
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
              };
let num =  Number(50000).toLocaleString("en", options);
console.log(num);
```